# Wake server during suspend (No Wake On Lan / Advanced bios settings)

Tags: suspend, bios, wakeup, wakeonlan, standby

I have an HP Compaq Presario CQ62-242SF on ubuntu 20.04 server and I want to enable wake on lan.

I want to suspend it during inactivity and wake it up if a port is used

1. WakeOnLan

So the first solution is to enable WakeOnLan

So I enable it in command line and I get :

```
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
```

So it seems ok.

But I can't find wake on lan option in bios or power option.

I think I have to enable advanced bios settings, but how I can do that ?

Edit : HP block the access of advanced settings I think it's impossible to access them.

2. Do it without WakeOnLan

The second solution is to do it without WakeOnLan.

Can I create a powerstate like suspend to ram but with network enable ?

I've found "standby" powerstate, is network still working in this mode ?

I can't do

```
sudo rtcwake -m standby -s 5
```

output :

```
unrecognized suspend state 'standby'
```

because there is no "standby" in :

```
cat /sys/power/state
freeze mem
```

So I have tried :

```
sudo echo standby > /sys/power/state
```

or

```
echo standby | sudo tee /sys/power/state
```

But impossible to write in this file

Does anybody have any idea to access my server during suspend ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this document. https://www.maketecheasier.com/enable-wake-on-lan-ubuntu/

Comment: As I sad I've already done this, I can receive magic packet when the laptop is on but I can't when it is suspended.
I think it's because I can't enable WakeOnLan in bios settings.